# Exceptional RewriteCond for some page

Tags: .htaccess

Let say i have domain like this `http://foo.com`
this domain as present use `.htaccess` to `RewriteCond`
and the `.htaccess` code is like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This Rewrite will happen to all page request,
now i want to change this to make this only happen to all page except this page:

```
http://foo.com/en/rates.htm
```

because in that page i want to do `301 redirect` like this `Redirect 301 /en/rates.htm http://www.google.com/index.html`

How to this in htaccess?

Thank you in advance,
GusDe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive you specified in your question **should** work, you can add it to your .htaccess file, before the Rewrite stuff block.

If it doesn't work still, maybe Apache has not loaded the mod_alias module, and then you can add this directive before the other Rewrite's  in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/en/rates\.htm http://www.google.com/index.html [R,L]
```

You could have a look at this [Apache docs page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html).