# Can I hide part of a page's filename from displaying in the URL bar?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Say I have four pages on my site: `001-earth.php`, `002-water.php`, `003-fire.php`, and `004-air.php`.

I want to display these files in a specific order when editing my site, for my own convenience, that's why I put the numbers in the filenames. But I don't want my site's visitors to see the numbers when they visit that page. I want to hide the numbers and the dashes that follow in the browser's address bar.

My question is: is it possible to hide the numbers (`001-`, `002-`, etc.), from the URL, but not remove them from the filename, so that when someone visits the file located at `http://example.com/001-earth.php`, the browser's address bar actually displays `http://example.com/earth.php`?

If so, how?

Comment: Read about regular expression.

Comment: You can use .htaccess file for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275725/exceptional-rewritecond-for-some-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/?earth.php /001-earth.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?water.php /002-water.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?fire.php /003-fire.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?air.php /004-air.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No problem, do not forget to "up" the post as well. Thanks!